# Trouble trying to 'logic' something out (also the syntax/ArrayList help)

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

So, I'm writing an android app for my boss. Currently, the way we have it work is:

MainActivity.java creates User.java objects. It will only ever create 1 of these. User will store information about the person (our customer).

User objects will create and populate Account objects. A user can have multiple accounts with us that our app has to be aware of.

Accounts will create and populate Group objects. A user can be in multiple groups within multiple accounts.

I'm doing it now by creating the user object in MainActivity as:

//empty constructor for testing
User usr = new User();

User creates account objects and stores them in an ArrayList. Here's where my first problem is coming in... I don't quite understand the syntax I suppose.. because whenever I call something like:

index = 1-x; //whatever number I want to get
System.out.println(accountarray.getacctname(accountarray.get(index)));

//The above should call "get account name" on the index of accountarray at index. However, it only //seems to return the most recent item.

it only seems to return the most recently-added account object?

Account objects create and store groups in ArrayLists, similar to User and Account.

Or, we have:

User --creates*-- Accounts -- creates* -- Groups

Creates* == creates and stores in an ArrayList.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Specifically, why is it only returning the last-in object?

Comment: 1) Post the actual code.  Better still, post the relevant parts of the code. 2) Take time to make your questions more intelligible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the information of all the entries in the ArrayList.

If they all say what is in the most recent one, then maybe you forgot to put a "new" somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's some of the relevant code. subID is the name of the "Account" class. "subids" is the array list of Account classes. Let me know if any other relevant code would be helpful.

```
    subID subs = new subID("1", "7939","1d", "1");
    subID subs0 = new subID("2", "7939","1dde", "1");
    subID subs1 = new subID("3", "791239","1dasd", "1");
    subID subs2 = new subID("4", "7933149","1dfdsa", "1");      
    subids.add(subs);
    subids.add(subs0);
    subids.add(subs1);
    subids.add(subs2);
    int index = 1;
    System.out.println(subids.get(index).getsubname());
    System.out.println(subids.get(subids.size()-1).getsubname()+"This should be the second to last entry");
    System.out.println(subids.size());
```